# events.js:141 TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to fetch all the requirement details from MongoDB using node.js and Angular and display it in a grid. When I am trying to get the data from MongoDB to node.js I am not able to pass on my data. I get the error as above.

My Server.js file:

```
exports.getRequirement=function(req,res)
{
    RequirementModel.find({}, function(error, requirement) {
        if(!error)
        {
            console.log(requirement);

           res.send(null,requirement);
        }
        else
        {
           console.log(error);
             res.send(error);
        }
    });

};
```

My Router Page:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
module.exports = function (app) {      


    router.get('/RequirementList', function(req, res) {

        addRequirement.getRequirement(function (error, requirement) {
            if (error) return next(error);
            res.send({state: 'success', requirement:requirement});
        })
    });


    return router;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass req, res as argument for  `getRequirement` , but in ur case you are passing callback function. Try for the below code

```
router.get('/RequirementList', function(req, res) {
        addRequirement.getRequirement(req, res)
    });
```

Comment: How will i pass my response from router page to controller page?

Comment: Server.js file ....i have three pages one for controller one for router and one for connecting DB that is server page,js.... I got the error in server page.js the first set of code...When i changed the code as you mentioned above i dont see any error but still the grid is showiNG AS EMPTY

Comment: My Controller Page: $http.get('requirement/RequirementList')      .success(function(data) {  
            if(data.state == 'success'){           
               $scope.gridOptions.data =data ;
                $location.path('Dashboard');   }
            else{
                $scope.error_message = data.message;
                $rootScope.sess = null;
            }    });});

Comment: I am not well versed in angular, but my guess is that change ` if(data.state == 'success'` to `if(data){}`, and try,, Also your console.log(requirement) is printing data??

Comment: Yes it is printing the entire set of data my problem is i am not able to send data from there to router page and from router to controller

Comment: Thanks a million it worked thank you sooo much for the help..Changing Controller page worked